# Short story about klopps, cats & timebombs

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm looking for the name and author of a short story about humans who send a time bomb into the past that forces a population of cats to evolve into their protectors in their current dangerous circumstance.  The story also depicts a planet populated only by men, some of whom mutate into substitutes for females called klopps.

Answer (score 10):

That is ["The Crime and Glory of Commander Suzdal"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Crime_and_the_Glory_of_Commander_Suzdal) by Cordwainer Smith, one of his *Instrumentality of Mankind* stories.

To quote from the linked Wikipedia article:

> When he arrives he learns the horrible truth. The original settlers
>   nearly became extinct, succumbing to a plague that (in Smith's words)
>   rendered "femininity carcinogenic." They were only able to save their
>   women by chemically (and later genetically) making them male. However,
>   the resulting society is deeply unbalanced by the lack of females and
>   ordinary family structure. The Arachosians, not truly male or female
>   and calling themselves "klopts", realize on an instinctive level what
>   they are missing and as a result, hate normal human beings with
>   unbridled fervor and regard them as abominations to be destroyed (even
>   though they have not seen one in many generations). To carry out this
>   plan, they have dispatched traps in the form of messages, such as the
>   one Suzdal encountered, throughout the galaxy.
>
> When Suzdal wakes up, the Arachosians are already crawling over the
>   outside of his ship. On the advice of an artificial security officer,
>   he uses an emergency device intended to send his large spacecraft back
>   a few seconds in time to instead hurl feline genetic material (coded
>   to evolve for intelligence and to obey Suzdal) millions of years back
>   on the far side of the local moon. A race of advanced, space-faring
>   cat-descendants appears instantaneously and hail Suzdal as their god
>   and creator. They engage the Arachosians at his order, allowing him to
>   escape.

Comment: Holy gosh and golly, I cannot thank you enough for the information.  I may even send a data packet into the past that will allow you to game the stock market and become very wealthy--if time allows, that is.  :)