# Short 70s(?) sci-fi story about smuggler sending cat embryo back in time to serve man and save him from alien pirates

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The Title pretty much says it all. This story was in an anthology I read in middle school and can't quite identify to replace.

The space smuggler is attacked by an alien race, codes the instruction to "serve man" into the cat DNA, then sends it to a nearby planet back millions of years. Immediately, in the "present", the cat race, which has evolved, appears in their spaceships and destroys the pirates.

Comment: If it's Cordwainer Smith, then this has been asked before: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/141801/short-story-about-klopps-cats-timebombs/141807.

Comment: The old story was accepted via comment so closing this one as a duplicate of it.

Comment: [To serve man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_Serve_Man_(The_Twilight_Zone)), you say? I have known some cats that I suspected wanted to do that....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Cat DNA being sent back in time is one of the major plot points of [Cordwainer Smith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cordwainer_Smith)'s "[The Crime and the Glory of Commander Suzdal](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?57038)" (1964).

> When Suzdal wakes up, the Arachosians are already crawling over the
> outside of his ship. On the advice of an artificial security officer,
> he uses an emergency device intended to send his large spacecraft back
> a few seconds in time to instead hurl feline genetic material (coded
> to evolve for intelligence and to obey Suzdal) millions of years back
> on the far side of the local moon. A race of advanced, space-faring
> cat-descendants appears instantaneously and hail Suzdal as their god
> and creator. They engage the Arachosians at his order, allowing him to
> escape.

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Crime_and_the_Glory_of_Commander_Suzdal)

Since this a fairly specific detail, this is a likely candidate, even though other details do not match (e.g. the eponymous Commander Suzdal is not a smuggler).

Comment: That's certainly the one I immediately thought of, at least.

Comment: Usually Cordwainer Smith is just weird (which is good IMO), but alas this is one of the more unpleasant ones, to the extent that it comments on sex and gender.

Comment: @EikePierstorff "Do not read this story; turn the page quickly. The story may upset you. Anyhow, you probably know it already. It is a very disturbing story."

Comment: Yes, you all have it. This is the one I meant. Sorry for the duplicate question, I couldn't quite figure out how to search for previously asked ones (newbie). Thank you so much! I had lost this story *twice* lol.

Comment: @Sabaki12 You can accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark next to the correct answer!

Comment: @Sabaki12 since I already knew the answer I could search for the name. "Suzdal" is quite distinctive. I think this would have been really hard to find otherwise, so don't apologize.